# different way for imsubtract in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, subtraction

I am reading Matlab code and I saw two different types for image arrays subtraction. So, I write here to confirm that it is possible to do it using diffent ways and that I do not make I mistake.

array1 = array2 - array3;

array1 = imsubtract(array2, array3);

Comment: you could try array of mpougatsa {tyri, kyma, crema, merenda}

Comment: Wow , are you from Greece? Greek bugacha sounds familiar to me, i've taste it, it's really nice. eeee basically sorry.

Comment: user311590 if my answer was useful please accept it (unless someone else appears with a better one) so I can get the points, thanks.
@SoulMagnet mpougatsa=[mpougatsa ' spanaki']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As found in the `help imsubtract`:

```
'You can use the expression X-Y instead of imsubtract.'
```

So yes, it seems to be the same. Generally in Matlab you can do something using various ways, and that's what gives to Matlab its very useful flexibility.